# Why does gcc make "!(T_MAX+T_MAX+2)" equal to 0?

Tags: c, gcc

For gcc 9.3.0, when I try to print it as

```
int x = 0x7fffffff;
printf("%d", !(x+x+1+1));
```

it gives me 0. But when I try to print it as

```
int temp = (x+x+1+1);
temp = !temp;
printf("%d", temp);
```

it gives me 1 as expected.
What happens?

Comment: `x+x` is `int` overflow and _undefined behavior_.  Expectations are not supported by C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As OP said "1 as expected", I assert the result of 0 or 1 as an expected result  is not supported due to the UB in both.

Comment: Signed integer overflow in C is, indeed, undefined behavior, but **unsigned** integer "overflow" is well defined, and is going to behave the way you expect here.